# Asus 1001PXD and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, asus, eeepc

There is a web site that contains information about Ubuntu 12.04 suits very well with the ASUS EEE PC 1001PXD model.

I'd like to ask anybody used 14.04 with that model of Asus.

Here is the link http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201202-10627/

I wonder if Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty 64 bit fully supports Asus EEEPC 1001PXD.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always run Live CD and see what happens. At the Live CD first screen choose "Try" first, not "Install". By the time you get this screen all important things such as Linux Kernel and most interesting subsystems have been already started.

It covers display/video, network, sound, input, hard and optical drives and others.

As the same configuration and binaries go to the installed version this means if it works in Live CD it is most likely going to work after installation.